# How to create JSONModel class of key value is Object or Array

Tags: ios, arrays, nsdictionary, jsonmodel

in my response some time is

```
 "url": {
    “full_img”: "imagelink",
    “id”: “1”,
    “small_img”: "imagelink",
   }
```

and some time array

```
"url": [
      {
       “full_img”: "imagelink",
       “id”: “1”,
       “small_img”: "imagelink",
      },
      {
       “full_img”: “imagelink”,
       “id”: “2”,
       “small_img”: "imagelink",
      }]
```

in this i create a [JsonModel](https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel) Class but how i can declare that url class as array or as a object, or i have to create two class for url+json?

now if the Url is Array that time i don't have any issue but when it become Object it give Error like.

**Error Domain=JSONModelErrorDomain Code=1 "Invalid JSON data. The JSON type mismatches the expected type. Check the error user information." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid JSON data. The JSON type mismatches the expected type. Check the error user information., kJSONModelTypeMismatch=Property ‘url’ is declared as NSArray* but the corresponding JSON value is not a JSON Array., kJSONModelKeyPath=url**

Comment: Let's say that the API is wrong here. It should always return an array! You can just try to reflect the value type of `url` key in the dictionary

Comment: @LucaD No api is not Wrong, it is like yahoo cricket Api, if first inning is running that time it give a object (batting detail of first team) but if second is running that time it become a array(in index 0 it give first team detail and index 1 it give  second team batting detail).

Comment: Adopting generic REST Guidelines, you are now retrieving a list of `Images` accessing to an url like `/images`. That means that you want a `list` aka `array`. If the image is just one it shouldn't matter

Comment: how you tried my ans..

Answer (score 0):

1) Your Model class should be like this

```
@interface Image : NSObject

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString * fullImage;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString * id;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString * smallImage;
```

2) You shoul hold `Image` objects in Array & use it using index

3) The advantage of using Array is you can use it with `tableView` & `collectionView` very effieciently using `indexpath`

4) After parsing the response you can check the response by checking class & make the Model Object like below

```
id responseData=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
 if ([responseData isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
     {
        //parse response and add in imageArray
     }
 else if ([responseData isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
     {
         //parse each object by enumerating the array & add the parsed object in Image Array

     }
```

> You need not to create two objects instead you can reuse the same
>   `Image` Object